# How to only allow a certain number of click events per column? And also per page? With only Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

Making a connect 4 using vanilla JavaScript. Using an event listener "click" to insert a colored disk into a column. The disks keep stacking infinitely. I need it to stop after 6. And then 42 total.
I have it divided into 7 columns. Each having their own event handler for the "click". How do I get it to insert each click into an array?
https://youtu.be/Jqm5m75pq6A
Here is an example of what I have

```
let gameBoard = [
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
];


let column0 = document.querySelector("#column0");
let column1 = document.querySelector("#column1");
let column2 = document.querySelector("#column2");
let column3 = document.querySelector("#column3");
let column4 = document.querySelector("#column4");
let column5 = document.querySelector("#column5");
let column6 = document.querySelector("#column6");
column0.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // console.log("column 1");
    if (currentPlayer === 1) {
        // column1.innerHTML =
        let black = document.createElement("span");
        black.className = "blackDisc";
        column0.append(black);
        currentPlayer += 1;
        console.log("Current player:" + currentPlayer);
        discCount++;
        gameBoard[5][0] = 1;
        console.log(currentPlayer);
    } else if (currentPlayer === 2) {
        let red = document.createElement("span");
        red.className = "redDisc";
        column0.append(red);
        currentPlayer -= 1;
        console.log("current player:" + currentPlayer);
        discCount += 1;
        gameBoard[5][0] = 2;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just count how many child elements are in the column.

```
let column0 = document.querySelector("#column0");
column0.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if ( column0.querySelectorAll( 'span' ).length < 7 ) {
        // do game logic here only if there aren't 6 spans in the column
```

You can do similar for all spans on the entire board if you have reference to an outer container to do the `querySelectorAll()` from.

The other option would be to store your data in your `gameBoard` array and check the values. This way would probably be faster, but a little more complicated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to store the data in the gameBoard?

Comment: @PeteyP I mean if this was my game, i would set up the gameBoard as an array filled with empty arrays, instead of an array of arrays filled with nulls. then each time a piece is dropped into a certain column, you would add the color value to the array using the array's  `push()` method. then all you gotta do is check the array's length to see if it has 6 pieces yet.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the time you took to answer my questions! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just start with empty arrays, so you don't have to iterate them on each click and count how many items already in the array of clicked column:

```js
let currentPlayer = 1;
//starting with empty arrays;
let gameBoard = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];

for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  const column = document.getElementById("column" + i);
  column.addEventListener("click", function(e)
  {
    //check if current column has 7 items
    if (gameBoard[i].length > 6)
      return;
    
    //add item to the column
    gameBoard[i].push(currentPlayer);
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = (currentPlayer == 1 ? "black" : "red") + "Disc";
    column.appendChild(span);
    currentPlayer = !--currentPlayer + 1;
//        console.log("Current player:" + currentPlayer);
//        console.log("gameBoard", gameBoard);
  });
}
```

```css
.content
{
  display: flex;
}

.content > *
{
  width: 1.3em;
  height: calc(1.2em * 7 + 0.1em);
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.blackDisc,
.redDisc
{
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.blackDisc
{
  background-color: black;
}

.redDisc
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="column0"></div>
  <div id="column1"></div>
  <div id="column2"></div>
  <div id="column3"></div>
  <div id="column4"></div>
  <div id="column5"></div>
  <div id="column6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I do this so it starts at the bottom of the board instead of the top?

Comment: set columns as `display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;`

Comment: That was it. Thank you for all your help. Any advice on how to determine the if its a tie or a winner? I created an array with all the possible combinations. Just unsure how to tye it all in.